# Generic Error webhook for integromat scenario

Tags: make.com

So I know at each step of a scenario I can setup an error handler to call a webhook, but does anyone know if it's possible to just fire a webhook if the scenario fails anywhere?

Reason: I want to send failures to OpsGenie as the current email notification thing is daft and prone to getting missed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. List all scenarios https://www.make.com/en/api-documentation/scenarios-get
2. Filter active scenarios with "islinked" parameter
3. Get logs every 5 minutes for the last 5 minutes https://www.make.com/en/api-documentation/scenarios-scenarioId-logs-get
4. Filter by status warning or error
5. Pull information to OpsGenie

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Legend!